# How do I decline a dinner invitation from a superior?

Tags: professionalism

Recently I think what we're being asked of is really unrealistic, and I am growing tired of it and I'm done with pretending that everything is okay. What I'm doing is every work they throw at me, I just do it to the best of my abilities.

Now, the higher ups deem it fit to throw a dinner to celebrate what we're doing so far, and I can't just grin and bear it. Since it won't be on the clock anyway, how do I decline the invitation when everyone is expected to attend? I'm afraid I'll just bring the mood down, so I don't want to go.

Update: thanks people, most of you were upfront and frank, and I guess I see the error of my ways, I guess I'll just stomach it a bit more since it'll end soon anyway. Thank you for all your advice.

Comment: "Recently I think what we're being asked of is really unrealistic" That sounds as if there is more going on than just that dinner invitation. If so, give us facts instead of your conclusions.

Comment: Tasks are expected to be completed within a day when only a fraction of those could realistically be done properly and everybody knows it. Overtime is expected, and if you don't render it then you'll be seen as someone who's not doing your work properly. Everyone working is having a hard time.

Comment: @NoThanks So don't work overtime?  Will they honestly lay you off?  Probably not, there is a very good chance that this is just sales and project management bullying the workers.  Even if they threaten and follow through with it what is the worst that will happen to you?  You get unemployment for a little while until you find something significantly better.

Comment: I rarely turn down a chance to stuff my face with free food :) If I am in a sour mood, I stuff my face, socialize, have a good time and then I go back to my sour mood.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a new job right now as I live in the poverty and people are depending on me. If it was that easy I would have done it. It's not that easy. You're correct though, some people above are pushing for us to go through with this, and everyone at the bottom is suffering.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan maybe you're right :)

Comment: My attitude is that no employer can buy me happiness with just free food. Or with free food and more money. But would I discourage them from trying and trying harder? Hell no - I'd say, it's hopeless but you folks keep trying :)

Comment: The question is how do I decline an invitation to something they think is worth celebrating over when both parties know(me and them) that the reason I'm declining is because I was not happy with what they made us do.

Comment: You could decline and cite that you have to decline because you are exhausted from the workload and you need whatever time is available to you after work to sleep it off.

Comment: @NoThanks Our advice might be more helpful if you specify what country you live in.  I can't imagine it is a good country if IT professionals are working evenings and weekends and still living in poverty.

Comment: I don't understand how your personal financial situation prevents you from finding another job.  Nobody said quit and *then* look.  Usually you look and quit when you've found something.

Comment: Seize the opportunity and go - you never know how the dinner could be useful in other ways.  Two years ago I received a similar distasteful work-related dinner invitation.  I used it to heavily network with as many people there as I could, and got a very good contact out of it (a recruiter) that has helped tremendously.  You just never know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A celebratory dinner for a whole group is not the same as "a dinner invitation from a superior" - that implies your boss wants to take you, perhaps you and one or two other people, for a quiet dinner and private chat. What you're describing is perhaps an acknowledgement that what was asked of your group recently was unrealistic, and an expression of gratitude that you handled everything that was thrown at you.

Look at your team-mates. Have they worked extra hard lately too? Do they deserve a thankyou and a bit of applause? I bet they do. You should go, so you can give them that. Someone may give you that, too. And at some point, a higher-up may stand up and give a bit of a speech that will give you some important insight into what's been going on, and whether it's the "new normal" or has finished now.

I appreciate that you don't want to sit at a dinner sulking and thinking "but what's been going on was awful and stupid and not something to celebrate." Staying away from the dinner won't help anything though. Instead, try to see whether what's been going on was awful and difficult and **for a reason** and has now concluded successfully. The dinner can celebrate what you all have done **and** the return to normal operations. Or it can usher in the new era of always being like this, which will probably be your cue to look for a new job. But you'll do so with a better understanding of what's happening in this one.

Comment: Well, if by their definition of extra hard is putting everyone's health at risk by asking them to stay late every day and work on weekends would this still apply? A lot of us already had sickness in different days and none of those stemmed from laziness but pure fatigue.

Comment: @NoThanks Nobody is chaining you to a chair dude. They just "asked" you. Tell them no and that you have plans and don't show up. 9 times out of 10 they will stop asking you and just leave you alone. Have sour grapes all you want but it was your choice to stay late and to go into work in the evenings.

Comment: That's what I probably forgot to say, it was do what they want or find another job. It's not optional for everyone. It's oppressive.

Comment: NoThanks: I suspect you're misreading that. If you aren't, you really have only two choices: Deal with it, or leave.

Comment: But it is only a short term project, I forgot to add.